# MIPS and Assembly finding the sections of a parameter block

Tags: debugging, assembly, mips

In a function, the arguments given contains a parameter block. In that parameter block the first two sections contain separate strings, and the third section will store the combined string. How do determine the address locations of the sections of the parameter block?

Comment: can you post an example?  a label is an address, you want the address of something just put a unique label there.

Comment: Yes.Register a0 is the address of a parameter block. For that address, it contains for words.  1. The address of a string. 2. The address of the string. 3. The address of another string 4. The length of the strings. How do I access those values?

Answer (score 0):

Perform Indexing or Indirect Addressing.

Here's an example:

```
.data
.align  2

problem1:
    .word   str_a1      # First number
    .word   str_a2      # Second number
    .word   buf_a       # Place to store the result
    .word   1           # Length of both numbers and result buf
    .word   out_a       # Where to start printing the answer


.text
...

la    $a0,problem    # Address of parameters for
jal   print_label    #   problem 1, and do it.


print_label:
...
move    $s0, $a0        # copy the loc of the parm block to s0

li  $v0, 4              # print 1st number  
lw  $a0, 0($s0)
syscall

li  $v0, 4              # print 2nd number  
lw  $a0, 4($s0)         # Indexing!
syscall


li  $v0, 4              # print newline at end  
la  $a0, result3
syscall
```

The label representations are irrelevant. In essence the contents of $a0 are copied into $s0 and are accessed with indexing. If you were to increment its 'pointer' then that would be indirect displacement.

Perform whatever operations and they can be saved at a displaced location in the parameter block $a0 then read out as shown in the label problem1.